# Any way to have long text (memo) parameters in DAO and MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, dao, ms-access-2010

I've searched all over for information on this, and it seems like DAO paramaters in Access are restricted to 255 characters.

Really?  Still?  Even in Office 2010?  It seems absurd.  I'd prefer not to switch to ADO, but at this point it seems like I'll have to.

Is there any way to work around this while still using DAO and VBA code?

And are there any methods at all that allow using named parameters in queries that are over 255 characters in length, DAO or otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your choice is dynamic sql, a recordset or ADO, I am afraid.

[Access Specifications 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx)

And it's the same for 2013 as far as I can tell from a test.

Comment: See added note. It is not going to go way.

Answer (score 2):

I've done sometime in access 2000 this including the contents of the memo field inside the sql statement, not as a paramenter. In order to do this, I had first to preprocess the memo field to duplicate each " inside the memo.

Hope it helps.